# Mysqli prepare error: Commands out of sync;

Tags: zend-framework, stored-procedures

Commands out of sync Error occur when executing this code.

```
foreach ($groupsId as $gpId) {

            $stmt = $db->query("CALL addUserToGroup(?,?)", array($userId, $gpId));
        $stmt->execute();


 }
```

This error occur

```
 Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Mysqli prepare error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in /var/www/html/zend/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php:77 Stack trace: #0
```

here's the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE addUserToGroup(IN groupId INT(11),IN userId INT(11) )

   BEGIN
        insert into `group_users`(`group_id`,`user_id`) values(groupId ,userId );
   END //

 DELIMITER ;
```

What should I do ???

Comment: Did it ever work? Is your data verified to be of correct type? It's a really simple looking prepared statement, although it looks like your variables are being passed backwards. Shouldn't `$gpId` be at position `0` in the array?

Comment: I try it locally and it works properly but the error occure when I work online.

Comment: I need a solution for this problem please :(

Comment: see if this has any info to help...http://stackoverflow.com/q/614671/1145086

Comment: This is with PHP, my problem occurs with stored procedure..

Comment: I understand, but your error is from the MySqli extension not from Mysql or Sql. Maybe try the PDO_Mysql extension and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
foreach ($groupsId as $gpId) {

    $stmt = $db->query("CALL addUserToGroup(?,?)", array($userId, $gpId));
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    //or $result = $query->fetchAll();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

Should work :)