# problems with JSON Decode & strings

Tags: php, mysql, json

having a bit of an issue here. I'm passing data over an AJAX command to my php script. The data travels across fine.

**Print_r**

```
Array 
( [0] => stdClass Object 
    ( [Loc] => Main Door 
      [Module] => O2 
      [Dect] => O2 
      [GasDec] => O2 
      [ScB4] => 
      [ScA4] => 
      [A1] => 
      [A2] => 
      [CalGas] => 
      [CalGasA] => 
      [Factor] => 
      [ZB4] => 
      [ZA4] => 
      [CalB4] => 
      [CalA4] => 
      [CHNoID] => 5 
      [JobID] => 3 )
)
```

I can use The following method just fine but when i use option two it doesn't like it due to this error message:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

**Methods**

```
//Method one
echo "JobID: " . $comm[0]->JobID; // result: 3
//Method two
echo "JobID: '$comm[0]->JobID'"; // get error message
```

The reason im using method two is so I can pass the information into mysql. If anyone knows something i'm missing or it can't be done or even a easier way. please say.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

**Query**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
  calinfo (Sbefore, Safter, A1, A2, CalGas, Factor, Zbefore, Zafter, Cbefore, Cafter, SysInfoID)
  VALUES
  ('$comm[$i]->ScB4', '$comm[$i]->ScA4', '$comm[$i]->A1', '$comm[$i]->A2', '$comm[$i]->CalGasA', '$comm[$i]->Factor', '$comm[$i]->ZB4', '$comm[$i]->ZA4', '$comm[$i]->CalB4', '$comm[$i]->CalA4', '$comm[$i]->CHNoID');";

  $sql .= "UPDATE
  jobs
  SET
  CompletedBy = $tech
  WHERE JobID = '$comm[$i]->JobID';"; //<-- when i try the method of "WHERE JobID = ".$comm[$i]->JobID.";"; it doesnt like it...
```

Comment: then need to show your query and in mehtod two you are converting in string of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$sql .= "UPDATE
jobs
SET
CompletedBy = $tech
WHERE JobID = '".$comm[$i]->JobID."'";
```

Comment: Hi, ive tried that it works ok but it has problems with my WHERE clause (check Query edit of main post)

Comment: ok works but i get this message: 'Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. from my sql multi query? any answers?

Comment: Check this post for error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554517/php-commands-out-of-sync-error

Answer (score 2):

You may need to do as

```
echo "JobID: '{$comm[0]->JobID}'";
```

So in the query u can use it as `where some_col = '{$comm[0]->JobID}'`

Comment: Hi, i seem to get this error when using the "{}" : 'Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: `WHERE JobID = '{$comm[$i]->JobID}'` is the correct format or WHERE `JobID = "'.$comm[$i]->JobID."'` also you have insert query as well make sure they are all in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message saies, the return cannot be converted to fit into a string directly.

```
echo sprintf( "JobID: '%s'",$comm[0]->JobID);
```

or

```
echo "JobID: '{$comm[0]->JobID}'";
```

or

```
echo "JobID: '" . $comm[0]->JobID . "'";
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Simple double quotes won't interpolate complex combinations like this. You need to use curly braces to achieve this, e.g. `echo "JobID: {$comm[0]->JobID}";`.

You could however also use `printf`, e.g. `printf("JobID: %s", $comm[0]->JobID);`.