# php mysqli command cannot be executed now error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update my SQL table with the help of this php code:

```
$description = "Something about myself";
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO kys_write (Author, writing , Title , Description , Assets) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ssssi",$author,$data,$title,$description, $ImageExist);
$insert->execute();

$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM kys_write WHERE Title=?");
$statement->bind_param("s",$title);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($lastId);

//Everything works fine if this whole part is removed
$sql = "UPDATE  kys_essentials SET LastId=".$lastId;
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}
```

I am getting a error:

> **Error updating records:Commands out of sync, you cannot run this command now**.

What causes this, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Commands Out of Sync error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554517/php-commands-out-of-sync-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: i have seen both of the above but it dint help!

Answer (score 1):

It clear that the result sets of a prepared statement execution need to be fetched completely before executing another prepared statement on the same connection.

You can simplify you code using one query  . no use of extra select query

```
$sql = "UPDATE  kys_essentials SET LastId = (SELECT id FROM kys_write WHERE Title='$Title')";
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou i tried it but i am getting a error called check the manual correspond to your my sql to use near IN

Comment: Add quotes around `Title='$Title'` and chack

Comment: Use `=` in place of `in`

Comment: Or you can try with `$sql = "UPDATE  kys_essentials SET LastId = '(SELECT id FROM kys_write WHERE Title='$Title')'";` By adding quotes in select query

Comment: Have you check the above suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your `$lastId` after the binding and put `' '` for value/s, like this:

```
//your codes
$statement->bind_result($lastId);

while ($statement->fetch()){
      $sql = "UPDATE kys_essentials SET LastId='".$lastId."'";
      if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Record updated successfully";
      } else{
          echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
      }
}
```