# Multiple CSV File Creation in PHP

Tags: php, opencsv

I have a code below

```
<?php  
    /* Error display */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

    /* Requires */
    require 'conn.php';

    /* Parameters (DIM) */
    $param_customer                = $_POST['param_customer'];
    $param_user                    = $_POST['param_user'];

    /* Others */
    $param_email    = $_POST['email'];
    $file_dump_area = "../general_sync/";

    /* Array */
    $jsonData     = array();
    $arr_result   = array();

    /******************************** Download customer      *********************************/
    $cur_filename = $file_dump_area . removeCharEmail($param_email)  . "_" . $param_customer . ".csv";
    $cur_file     = fopen($cur_filename, "w");
    $cur_sql      = "CALL android_getCustomer('" .$param_email. "')";
    $cur_result   = mysqli_query($con,$cur_sql);

    if ($cur_file && $cur_result) {
        while ($row = $cur_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            fputcsv($cur_file, array_values($row));
        }
        array_push($arr_result, array('done_process' => "done_cus"));
    }
    fclose($cur_file);

    /******************************** Download user          *********************************/
    $cur_filename = $file_dump_area . removeCharEmail($param_email)  . "_" . $param_customer . "1.csv";
    $cur_file     = fopen($cur_filename, "w");
    $cur_sql      = "CALL android_getCustomer('" .$param_email. "')";
    $cur_result   = mysqli_query($con,$cur_sql);

    if ($cur_file && $cur_result) {
        while ($row = $cur_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            fputcsv($cur_file, array_values($row));
        }
        array_push($arr_result, array('done_process' => "done_user"));
    }
    fclose($cur_file);


    $jsonData = array("received"=>$arr_result);
    echo json_encode($jsonData,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    function removeCharEmail($val) {
        $new_val1 = str_replace(".", "", $val);
        $new_val2 = str_replace("@", "", $new_val1);
        return $new_val2;
    }
?>
```

The target output of that code is to create 2 csv which is it does but the problem is the 2nd csv has no data although the query shows some it does not write. I tried to copy the 1st line of codes. it does create the file but it didnt write

Whats the problem?

Updated with help of Mr. Barmar

i got this error `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: The two queries are the same. Is that really what you wanted? Why not write both files at the same time?

Comment: yes i did that for testing purposes to check if it does not write on the second one you will see the files where the data will write is different only the query. Actually I will make different CSV from different queries. my problem is when i run the second 1 there is no data created.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the second file is empty if the query is the same.

Comment: yeah me too. i dont know why. :(

Comment: You don't need to use `array_values()` if you use `MYSQLI_NUM`.

Comment: If you put `echo "writing row";` in the second loop, do you see that?

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: tried it and i noticed the second array push did not work

Comment: Then either `$cur_file` or `$cur_result` are false. Try `var_dump($cur_file, $cur_result)` to see which it is.

Comment: Add error checking when you open the file and perform the query.

Comment: `resource(7) of type (Unknown)
bool(false)` thats what i see

Comment: So the query failed. Add error checking. `$cur_result   = mysqli_query($con,$cur_sql) or die($con->error);`

Comment: what is this? `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Comment: search SO for that error message, you'll find many examples.

Comment: i did but i dont know how to apply that in my code.

Comment: It generally happens if you start another query while you haven't finished looping over the results of a previous query. I don't see how that would happen here, since you finish the first loop correctly.

Comment: thats true. i dont know does it happen

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561639/1491895) regarding this error when calling a stored procedure. Does the procedure perform multiple `SELECT` queries?

Comment: i think your link solves my problem

Comment: just added $cur_result->close();
      $con->next_result(); on the last row of every function

Comment: i hope you can make it as an answer so i can accept it and anyone will know it also

Comment: I made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procedure is apparently returning two result sets. You need to fetch the next result set before you can start another query. Add:

```
$cur_result->close();
$con->next_result();
```

After each loop that fetches the results. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561639/1491895 for more details.

Comment: tysm :) you made my day complete