# 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MySQL whose definition as below, which returns 4 ResultSets to the requesting script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetAllParts`;
delimiter ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAllParts`(
    IN inRefNo VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pType CHAR(1);
    DECLARE pMake SMALLINT(4); 
    SELECT VNo FROM `details` WHERE RefNo = inRefNo; # ResultSet 1
    SELECT * FROM deprates; # ResultSet 2
    SELECT `Type`, Make INTO pType, pMake FROM `details` WHERE RefNo = inRefNo; # ResultSet 3
    SELECT PartID, PartName, PartNo, PartTypeID FROM parts WHERE TypeID = pType AND MakeID = pMake; # ResultSet 4
END
;;
delimiter ;
```

Calling the proc from a PHP script takes minutes and returns error like ***"Fatal Error. Allowed memory size of xxxxxxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxxxx bytes)"***.

I called the proc directly in phpMyAdmin with `CALL GetAllParts('2021/0000012');`. An error instantly thrown is "***2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now***"

If I run the queries inside the proc in one go like below:

```
SELECT VNo FROM `details` WHERE RefNo = '2021/0000012';
SELECT * FROM deprates;
SELECT `Type`, Make FROM `details` WHERE RefNo = '2021/0000012';
SELECT PartID, PartName, PartNo, PartTypeID FROM parts WHERE TypeID = 3 AND MakeID = 3;
```

All the 4 ResultSets are retrieved successfully. I have several similar procs but they are not throwing any error. As per description about the problem [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) in dev.mysql.com, how do I use `mysql_use_result()`, `mysql_free_result()` and `mysql_store_result()` inside a procedure?

Any help please?

Comment: It may be useful to see the PHP code that is generating the error as it is in PHP that the error is happening

Comment: Did you change the delimiter anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly, You haven't read the question completely. Besides, if phpMyAdmin is throwing error, what is the point checking PHP code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561639/1766831