# PHP's mysqli functions, is freeing the statements necessary, and what's the difference between close and free_result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wasn't freeing my statements, as I didn't think it was necessary per se, as the manual says "mysql_free_result() only needs to be called if you are concerned about how much memory is being used for queries that return large result sets." so I didn't. But then I got an error saying: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" which only went away when I freed my results. Weird.

So is it necessary?

Also, what's the difference between `close()` and `free_result()`? In [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) they have close used to close statements (in one of the examples on this fetch manual). But they also use `free_result` [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php) and it's unclear the difference.

Comment: Re part 1 of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`_close`**

> Closes a previously opened database connection

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

**`_free_result`**

> Frees the memory associated with a result
>
> **Note:**
>
> You should always free your result with `mysqli_free_result()`, when your result object is not needed anymore.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

And as mentioned in the comments, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now) regarding the out of sync error.

Comment: But in that manual I linked (the fetch one) they're using close to close statements.