# No error, but still can't use 3 stored procedure in 1 pages php using database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a script that checks an IP address from database, then checks if the IP address is unique or not. If the IP address is not unique, it saves the IP Address to IP_history on database. It's working very slowly, that's why I converted it to mysql stored procedure, but it doesn't run the same. It only runs the 1st procedure. I need it to run 3 procedures in a single page.

Here is my code:

```
$server = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname
$username = 'xxx'; // MySQL username
$password = 'xxx'; // MySQL password
$dbname = 'xxx'; // MySQL db name


//$ipvisitor=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


if (isset($_GET['ip']) && $_GET['ip']) {

    $ipvisitor = $_GET['ip'];

} else {
    $ipvisitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


$db = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo $db->connect_error;
}


if ($result = $db->query("CALL cekip('$ipvisitor')")) {
    $db->error;
}


$dataip = $result->fetch_array();

$hitung = $result->num_rows;

if ($hitung == 0) {

    echo "Tidak Ada Dalam Database";

} else {

    $cekunik = $db->query("CALL cekhistory('$ipvisitor')");

    $unik = $cekunik->num_rows;


    if ($unik > 0) {

        echo "Sudah Pernah Masuk";

    } else {

        echo $dataip['country'];

        $addhistory = $db->query("CALL addhistory('$ipvisitor')");

    }


}
```

Why is it only running one call?
And what is the best approach to fix the issue?

Comment: You didn't print / echo out `$db->error;`, error may be already happening

Comment: Raptor, i echo $db->error; then i got "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: it needs to add `close()` and `next_result()` on everytime after doing a query.
then it's allow to add as much stored procedure in a pages.

thanks to Raptor for helping this. :)