# Error after calling mysql stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

Sorry for my english and sorry if this message composed incorrect - it is my first question.

I had lost 2 evenings when tried to resolve one interesting problem with mysql disconnecting, after procedure call. It's going to be more interesting, when I'll say, that problem is only with SELECT queries in procedures.

So, my example. I have 2 classes and procedure:

1) DBCONN - for connection and handle queries.

```
class DBCONN
{
    private $mysqlC = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CreateConnection();
    }

    public function __destruct() 
    {
        //$this->mysqlC->close();
    }

    private function CreateConnection()
    {
        $mC = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "root");

        if ($mC->connect_error)
            die('Bye. '.$mC->connect_errno."-".$mC->connect_error);
        else 
            $mC->set_charset("utf8");

        $this->mysqlC = $mC;
    }

    private function CloseConnection()
    {
        $this->mysqlC->close();
    }

    private function _error()
    {
        die('Bye. '.$this->mysqlC->connect_errno."-".$this->mysqlC->connect_error);
    }

    public function SetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
    {
        //$this->CreateConnection();

        $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

        if ($stmt->prepare($call) === FALSE) 
            $this->_error();

        if ($params && call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),     array_merge(array($types), $params)) === FALSE)
            $this->_error();
        if ($stmt->execute() === FALSE) 
            $this->_error();

        $insid = $stmt->insert_id;
        $affrows = $stmt->affected_rows;

        $stmt->close();

        //$this->CloseConnection();

        return array($insid, $affrows);
    }

    public function GetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
    {
        //$this->CreateConnection();
        //#LOOK HERE BEGIN
        print 'status = '.$this->mysqlC->ping();
        //#LOOK HERE END
        //print $call;

        $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

        if ($stmt->prepare($call) === FALSE) 
            $this->_error();

        if ($params && call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($types), $params)) === FALSE)
            $this->_error();

        if ($stmt->execute() === FALSE) 
            $this->_error();
        if ($stmt->store_result() === FALSE) 
            $this->_error();

        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
             $var[] = &$row[$field->name];

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $var);

        $arr = null;

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            foreach($row as $key => $val)
                $c[$key] = $val;

            $arr[] = $c;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        //$this->CloseConnection();

        return $arr;        
    }

}
```

2) BASEACTIONS - creates DBCONN object and sends text commands to it.

```
class BASEACTIONS
{
    private $conn = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new DBCONN();
    }

    private function CheckPassword($email = '', $pass = '')
    {
        //#LOOK HERE BEGIN
        $arr = $this->conn->GetData("CALL Login_Actions(-1, '$email', '', '$pass', '');"); 
        $arr = $this->conn->GetData("CALL Login_Actions(-1, '$email', '', '$pass', '');");
        //#LOOK HERE END

        return ($arr[0]['isTrue']==1 ? true : false);
    }

    private function UpdateSession($email)
    {
        if (!session_regenerate_id()) return false;
        $session = session_id();

        $this->conn->SetData(
            "CALL Login_Session(2, ?, ?)",
            "ss", 
            array(&$email, &$session)
        );

        return true;
    }


    public function LoginUser($email = '', $pass = '')
    {
        if (!$this->UpdateSession($email)) return false;
        if (!$this->CheckPassword($email, $pass)) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

3) Stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Login_Actions`(
_action INT, 
_vcEmail varchar(50),
_vcNickname varchar(20),
_vcPassword varchar(255),
_vcPasssalt varchar(10)
)
BEGIN

case _action
    when -1 then
        select md5(concat(md5(_vcPassword), vcPasssalt)) = vcPassword 'isTrue' from Login where vcEmail=_vcEmail;
    when 0 then
        select iId, vcEmail, vcNickname from Login;
    when 1 then
        insert into Login(vcEmail, vcNickname, dtDateAdd, vcPassword, vcPasssalt) values(_vcEmail, _vcNickname, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), md5(concat(md5(_vcPassword), _vcPasssalt)), _vcPasssalt);
end case;

END
```

Well... I've marked for you 2 blocks in these code like '//#LOOK HERE' - please, find it before.

If you will implement next code...

```
$BASE = new BASEACTIONS();
$BASE->LoginUser("mail@mail.com", "mypassword");
```

...page will return to you

```
status = 1
status = Bye. 0-
```

But if you will change "CALL Login_Actions(-1, '$email', '', '$pass', '');" on query which case procedure with these parameters "select md5(concat(md5($pass), vcPasssalt)) = vcPassword 'isTrue' from Login where vcEmail=$email;", you'll get OK result.

```
status = 1
status = 1
```

I can't understand - why mysql connection close everytime after PROCEDURE with SELECT? There are no problems with INSERT in PROCERUDE. Please, help - I'm tearing my hairs.

UPD: Error occurs in "if ($stmt->prepare($call) === FALSE) $this->_error();" of GetData method. First implement of it is OK, all the rest is bad.

Comment: Error codes are all 4 digits, the fact you're getting an error code of 0 indicates there isn't an error, and you're detecting it wrong. Try using `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` to see exactly where the call to _error is made from and check the documents related to the logic surrounding it, make sure you've got your logic correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Error occurs in "if ($stmt->prepare($call) === FALSE) $this->_error();" of GetData method. What do I need to do?

Comment: Looks like your connection is being closed, otherwise you'd get a real error message. Could you add a `print 'Close called';` type message into your close connection code, ensure that's not being called anywhere.

Comment: I've tested it - this message don't shows on a page.

Comment: But your ping on this line returns false, right? `print 'status = '.$this->mysqlC->ping();`

Comment: Yes. You can copy this code to your local machine and test it. There are enough information for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution. It is't pretty, but it works and helps to solve a problem with calling of many procedures in 1 connection.

I need to add this line in my GetData method.

```
$stmt->close();
while(mysqli_more_results($this->mysqlC))  //<<<<---- this line
    mysqli_next_result($this->mysqlC); //<<<<---- this line

return $arr;
```

So, final class is:

```
class DBConn
{
private $mysqlC = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $mC = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

    if ($mC->connect_error)
        $this->Error("Bye. ", $mC->connect_errno, $mC->connect_error);
    else
        $mC->set_charset("utf8");

    $this->mysqlC = $mC;
}

public function __destruct()
{
    $this->mysqlC->close();
}

private function IsConnected()
{
    return $this->mysqlC->ping();
}

private function Error($msg = '', $errno = 0, $error = '')
{
    die("Bye. {$msg} ".
               ($errno != 0 ? "errno: {$errno} - {$error}"
                            : "errno: {$this->mysqlC->errno} - {$this->mysqlC->error}"));
}

public function SetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

    if ($stmt->prepare($call) === false) {
        $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
    }

    if ($params) {
        $result = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),
                                              array_merge(array($types), $params));
        if ($result === false) {
            $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }
    }

    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
    }

    $insid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $affrows = $stmt->affected_rows;

    $stmt->close();

    return array($insid, $affrows);
}

public function GetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

    if ($stmt->prepare($call) === false) {
        $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
    }

    if ($params) {
        $result = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),
                                       array_merge(array($types), $params));
        if ($result === false) {
            $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }
    }

    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
    }

    $result = $stmt->store_result();
    if ( $result === false && !empty($stmt->error) ) { // failing!!! and throw away result
        $this->Error("", $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
    }

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
         $var[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $var);

    $arr = null;

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val)
            $c[$key] = $val;

        $arr[] = $c;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    while(mysqli_more_results($this->mysqlC))  //<<<<---- this line
        mysqli_next_result($this->mysqlC); //<<<<---- this line

    return $arr;
}
}
```

Thank you all, geeks!

Answer (score 0):

As you may have suspected, the issue was nothing to do with the 'mysql' connection, which was fine. After, i installed your code i got similar errors.

I have all your code here and it works. However, i have put a lot of debugging code in it and it is rather untidy currently.

The main issue you have is with the 'DBConn' class. The actual fault is that 'store_result' returns false validly and you treat false as an error. I have also amended the code to conform to coding standards, such as all 'control flow statements' such as 'if' must use braces. I restructured code slightly to make it easier to read for me.

*I have not changed the overall logic in any way.*

*It shows errors more clearly now*

It is working, but not very well tested, on PHP 5.3.18 and MySQL 5.5.16 on windows XP. 
Any issues then please post. I will sort them out.

The DBConn class:

```
<?php // 24321955/error-after-calling-mysql-stored-procedures

class DBConn
{
    private $mysqlC = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CreateConnection();
    }

    private function CreateConnection()
    {
        $mC = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "testmysql");

        if ($mC->connect_error)
            die('Bye. '.$mC->connect_errno."-".$mC->connect_error);
        else
            $mC->set_charset("utf8");

        $this->mysqlC = $mC;
    }

    private function CloseConnection()
    {
        $this->mysqlC->close();
    }

    private function _error($msg = '', $errno = 0, $error = '')
    {
        die("Bye. {$msg} ".
                   ($errno != 0 ? "errno: {$errno} - {$error}"
                                : "errno: {$this->mysqlC->errno} - {$this->mysqlC->error}"));
    }

    public function SetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
    {
        //$this->CreateConnection();

        $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

        if ($stmt->prepare($call) === false) {
            $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }

        if ($params) {
            $result = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),
                                                  array_merge(array($types), $params));
            if ($result === false) {
                $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
            }
        }

        if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
            $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }

        $insid = $stmt->insert_id;
        $affrows = $stmt->affected_rows;

        $stmt->close();

        //$this->CloseConnection();

        return array($insid, $affrows);
    }

    public function GetData($call, $types = null, $params = null)
    {
        $stmt = $this->mysqlC->stmt_init();

        if ($stmt->prepare($call) === false) {
            $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }

        if ($params) {
            $result = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),
                                           array_merge(array($types), $params));
            if ($result === false) {
                $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
            }
        }

        if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
            $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }

        $result = $stmt->store_result();
        if ( $result === false && !empty($stmt->error) ) { // sometimes no result is ok!
            $this->_error(__FILE__.__LINE__, $stmt->errno, $stmt->error);
        }

        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
             $var[] = &$row[$field->name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $var);

        $arr = null;

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            foreach($row as $key => $val)
                $c[$key] = $val;

            $arr[] = $c;
        }

        $stmt->close();

        //$this->CloseConnection();

        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a work. You helped me to get full describe of mistake and I found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now