# Execution of sql query in php script failing but succeeding in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have an insert sql query in a php script. The query executes in phpmyadmin, but when i place it in the php script,it does not execute. The error I get is "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now". Any inputs on what may be wrong?

The following is the php code:

```
<?php
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
 if ($request_method == 'POST') {

//retrieve request body
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

//write to stats file
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/stats/upload/resourceStats.json', 'a') or die("unable to open file\n");
fwrite($fp, $requestBody, strlen($requestBody));
fclose($fp);

//parsing config file
$monitoring_db_config = parse_ini_file("mySql/monitoringConfig.ini");
//Connect to DB    
$mysqli_con = mysqli_connect($monitoring_db_config['host'],$monitoring_db_config['username'],$monitoring_db_config['password']);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error\n');
}

//execute .sql file
$multi_query = file_get_contents("mySql/monitoring.sql");
if(mysqli_multi_query( $mysqli_con , $multi_query) == FALSE ){
    echo "multi query failed"."\n";
}

//Insert stats into table
$arr_stat = json_decode($requestBody, true);

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO server_resource_stats (server_id,time,resource,measure,unit) VALUES (1,100,'resource',100,'%');";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli_con,$sql_query) != TRUE) {
        echo "error inserting into table\n";
    }
//close DB connection    
$mysqli->close($mysqli_con);
}
?>
```

The .sql file is as follows:

```
/*Create database 'monitoring'*/
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS monitoring;

/*Use database 'monitoring'*/
USE monitoring;

/*Create table 'server_resource_stats'*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS server_resource_stats(id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,server_id INT(3) NOT NULL,time INT(12) NOT NULL,resource VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, measure FLOAT(12,4) NOT NULL, unit VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Instead of echoing out a text string echo out the [actual error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: The error it gives is : "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: I did see that. He uses mysqli_next_result. I not sure if I am supposed to store the result of the queries in d .sql file or not. And i am supposed to , then how do i use that stored value?

Comment: are you connected to the DB? :) it may sound like a stupid question but that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine without actually putting on my test server, try printing your query from within your script this will check your getting the data from your file correctly you can then copy and paste the printed query into phpmyadmin or to check that it works.

Comment: I did that. It is fetching from the file correctly. Also working fine in phpmyadmin. It gives error "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now". What i don't understand is why are the commands out of sync?

Comment: check here you cant run multiple querys at that level ie all within the mysqli multi queries function instead separate your queries. you can put them in an array and loop them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.maxdb-multi-query.php

Comment: But if i remove the insert query from my php script and execute only the queries in the .sql file as it is , all the queries get executed. The DB and the table are created.