# Stored procedure stopped other queries in PHP page MySql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I changed my codes from this

```
    $query = "SELECT first_id, first, webpage_id FROM first WHERE first= ?";
  $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $first);
  $stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $first_id = $row['first_id'];
    $first = $row['first'];
    $webpage_id = $row['webpage_id'];

echo '<div class="yellow container">
       <div class="alt">
        <div class="first_name left"><h1>'.$row['first'].'</h1></div>
        <div>
          <div class="add_sub"><input type="button" class="addsub" data-id="'.$row['first_id'].'" /></div>
        </div>
       </div>';

    $query = "SELECT webpage_id, url, explanation  FROM webpage WHERE webpage_id= ?";
      $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $webpage_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result_ce = $stmt->get_result();
```

Into this in order to use stored procedures in my website. My first codes work perfect but second one stop working after execute stored procedure correctly. It says **Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean on line 42**

```
$result = $connect->query("CALL selectfirst('$first')");

// all codes above stays same

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $first_id = $row['first_id'];
    $first = $row['first'];
    $webpage_id = $row['webpage_id'];

echo '<div class="yellow container">
       <div class="alt">
        <div class="first_name left"><h1>'.$row['first'].'</h1></div>
        <div>
          <div class="add_sub"><input type="button" class="addsub" data-id="'.$row['first_id'].'" /></div>
        </div>
       </div>';

    $query2 = "SELECT webpage_id, url, explanation  FROM webpage WHERE webpage_id= ?";
      $stmt = $connect->prepare($query2);
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $webpage_id);   //line 42
      $stmt->execute();
      $result_ce = $stmt->get_result();
```

my stored procedure written by `phpmyadmin gui`. I just wrote `SELECT * FROM first = ufirst;` and clicked create. Maybe problem is there?

**IMPORTANT!!** I used `trigger_error($connect->error."[$query2]")` after second sql and page says `*Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now[SELECT webpage_id, url, explanation FROM webpage WHERE webpage_id=53]*` What that means?

Comment: @its clearly change something in the 2nd sql command. Am i right? because first codes works perfect

Comment: yes i think so just let me look

Comment: Did you check the value and type of `$webpage_id`? Are you sure that it contains and `INTEGER` value?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr I checked all three rows coming from stored procedure. they works fine. i began to think problem is the version of PHP or MySQL which are coming from XAMPP

Comment: Try calling `mysql_free_result($result)` before you set up `$query2`. This sounds like an issue related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: i am doing `$result->free_result()` just before `$query2` but its not working again

Answer (score 0):

When you call an stored procedure it may result multiple resultsets, you must free all resultsets before to run another query, add this line after getting result from calling a stored procedure:

```
$connect->next_result();
```

And instead of use `while($row = $result->fetch_array()){...}` you can use `fetchAll` and iterate in resultset array, because when you use `next_result` the result resource will be loss.