# Why do bind_param() inside while loop doesn't work? return Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Why do `bind_param()` inside my `while` loop doesn't work?
I get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ...

What I'm going to do here is to show all data from `user` table (if `$key` not set) then,
I want to differentiate shown value using `if` statement. I have tried to execute prepared query in database manager, and it works. But in this case.. my query seems return false. So, any idea? here is the codes,

```
function cariTemen($key) {
    require 'settings.php';
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT user_id,nama_asli FROM user WHERE username LIKE ? OR nama_asli LIKE ?");
    $key = '%'.$key.'%';
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$key,$key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$nama);

    //MODIFIED FROM HERE
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $temen_id = $id;
        $username = $nama;

        $temen = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_temenan FROM temenan WHERE temen_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
        $temen->bind_param('ii',$temen_id,$my_id); //ERROR IS HERE
        $temen->execute();
        $temen->store_result();
        $jml= $temen->num_rows;

        if($jml > 0) {

            echo $username.' [Temenan]<br>';

        } else {

            echo $username.' <a href="add.php?user_id='.$temen_id.'"">Temenin</a><br>';
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

as [marcellorvalle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846535/marcellorvalle) said that mysql can not maintain 2 simultaneous queries, In this case, i need to store all the values into an array() variable. so the script would be like this :

```
$user_id = array(); 
$username = array();
$i = 0;

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $user_id[$i] = $id;
    $username[$i] = $nama;
    $i++;
}

$stmt->close();

for ($j= 0 ; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    $temen = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_temenan FROM temenan WHERE temen_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
    $temen->bind_param('ii',$user_id[$j],$my_id);
    $temen->execute();
    $temen->store_result();
    $jml= $temen->num_rows;

    if($jml > 0) {

        echo  '<a href="profil.php?user_id='.$user_id[$j].'"">'.$username[$j].'</a> [TeMeNan]<br>';

    } else {

        echo ' <a href="profil.php?user_id='.$user_id[$j].'"">'.$username[$j].'</a> <a href="add.php?user_id='.$user_id[$j].'"">[TeMeNin]</a><br>';

    }

}
$temen->close();
```

Comment: After you do `prepare()` do a `echo $conn->error;` and see what you get

Comment: Try espace the words, `user` and `username`

Comment: var_dump($temen) return false, and $temen->error return "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" ...

Comment: If the answeer below is correct, mark it as accepted.

Comment: should I mark it as accepted, if the answer below just guide me how to find the error, but the solution will be different for specified error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not `bind_param()` doesn't work but `prepare()`.
2. It doesn't work because prepared queries are unbuffered by default, and thus in order to run another query while you didn't get all the results from the first one, you have to call `store_result()` on the first query first.
3. **99 times of 100 when you do a nested query, it means that you should have been running a single query with [JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)**

Answer (score -1):

According to the message $temen seems not to be an object. Try to debug it using var_dump($temen). It seems the $conn->prepare is returning *false* for some reason and *false* is not an object.

You can check any error echoing $conn->error to see what happened.

Comment: var_dump($temen) return false, and $temen->error return "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" ...

Comment: Seems mysql can not maintain 2 simultaneous queries. Maybe you should fetch the first querie on a array, free the statement, and iterate over it. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: *obviously*, mysql can maintain 2 simultaneous queries

Comment: so, whats the problem?