# How to close the result set in mysqli prepared statement, but keep the statement - without buffering entire result?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use multiple prepared statements with the mysqli driver in PHP and getting the infamous error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Although I think this database API is atrociously brain-damaged, I do understand why I'm getting the error, as described by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now).

Several solutions are offered in this and various other answers I've found laying around, the only ones I've seen that seem to work involve

```
$stmt->store_result()
```

which buffers the entire result set.

However, I don't want to buffer the entire result set - I want to discard it without using (a large amount of) memory to store it!

All I want to do, is create a prepared statement, use `bind_param()` and `bind_result()` and `fetch()` to get some of the results, and then somehow **close the results so that I can reuse the statment later and run other queries until then**.

I've tried just about every way of getting the actual result object being used from the statement and explicitly closing that, and I've tried calling `next_result()` until it returns null.   Neither of those solutions prevents that error from appearing.

So, how can I close a result set and execute other prepared statements after a `fetch()`, without trashing the executed statement and having to re-parse the query?

```
$q = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id, typename, storageclass, tablename FROM _dbtype WHERE typename=?");
$q->bind_param("s", $typeName);
$q->bind_result($id,$typeName,$storageClass,$tableName);
$q->execute();
$q->fetch();  // ie.  only once
...  <something that does not destroy $q> ...
$q2 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM _storagetype");
```

Comment: It would surprise me greatly if you had to create a different connection for each prepared statement.   No other database I've used forces you do to anything so non-performant and silly...  =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [mysqli_stmt::free_result()](http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.free-result)
(and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-free-result.html for the hint that "If there is a cursor open for the statement, mysql_stmt_free_result() closes it.")

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT|MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error( sprintf('mysqli connect error (%d) %s', $mysqli->connect_errno, $mysqli->connect_error), E_USER_ERROR);
    die;
}
$mysqli->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sofoo ( id int auto_increment, primary key(id))');
$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO sofoo VALUES (),(),(),(),(),()');


$stmtA = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM sofoo WHERE id>1');
$stmtB = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM sofoo WHERE id<10 ORDER BY id DESC');


$stmtA->execute();
$stmtA->bind_result($id);
$stmtA->fetch(); echo $id, PHP_EOL;
$stmtA->free_result(); // without this the script ends with "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Commands out of sync;"

$stmtB->execute();
$stmtB->bind_result($id);
$stmtB->fetch(); echo $id, PHP_EOL;
```

If there are multiple result sets (i.e. if you *have to* use `next_result()`) you must call `free_result()`for each result set separately.

Comment: Ah, thanks!   I didn't even consider this function because the docs threw me:  "Frees the result memory associated with the statement, which was allocated by mysqli_stmt_store_result()".   So, I thought this was only for use with `store_result()`!.   Seems to work, however!