# Prepared statement returning False

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know there are many questions similar to my question. But I really can not figure the problem here. I have class named 'UsersClass' which is responsible on every task related to users. And I use mysqli prepare statement to insert or select data from the database, the problem is that in many cases prepare statement return false. I solved the issue by making new connection every while, but this caused another issue in other functions "2006: Mysql server has gone away" See code below please: 
Here and in other functions the prepare return false.

```
function isPostingAllowed() {
  $this->setPsSelectUsers($this->_connection->prepare("Select * from userpermissions where userpermissions.UserId = ? and userpermissions.PermissionId = 1"));
 $this->_psSelectUsers->bind_param('i',$this->UserId);
 $this->_psSelectUsers->execute();
        if ( false===$this->_psSelectUsers ) {
        die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->_connection->error));}
 if ($this->_psSelectUsers->fetch()){
     return true;
 }else{
     return false;
     }}


function setPsSelectUsers($stmt) {
    $this->unsetPsSelectUsers();
           // mysqli_close($this->_Connection);
           // $this-> __construct();

    $this->_psSelectUsers= $stmt;}
```

When I uncomment these two lines The first function will work and prepare staement will not return false, but in this case the following function will throw error 2006:

```
 function checkUserAuthentication() {
 $this->setPsSelectUsers($this->_connection->prepare("SELECT UserLogInName FROM Users WHERE UserLogInName=? AND UserPassword=?"));
 $this->_psSelectUsers->bind_param('ss',$this->UserLogInName, $this->UserPassword);
 $this->_psSelectUsers->execute();
 if ($this->_psSelectUsers->fetch()){
     return true;
 }else{
     return false;
     }}
```

So How to solve the first problem without making new problem?

Comment: What this `unsetPsSelectUsers()` method does? I'm suspecting something is wrong in here. Also, instead of calling `setPsSelectUsers()` method, why don't you directly do this: `$this->_psSelectUsers = $this->_connection->prepare(...);` ?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul
private function unsetPsSelectUsers() {
  if (isset($this->_psSelectUsers)) {
   $this->_psSelectUsers->close();
   unset($this->_psSelectUsers);}

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Yes I understand, but they are the same. the unsetPsSelectUsers() only unset the _psSelectUsers.

Comment: I've updated my answer below. I've given an explanation on what's causing this issue and the solution as well. Hopefully this will answer all your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem:

> ... I use mysqli prepare statement to insert or select data from the database, the problem is that in many cases prepare statement return false.

That's because you're running the queries in **out of order** fashion i.e. you're executing `->prepare()` before closing the previous statement object. Given your current code, add the following error reporting code in your prepared statements,

```
if(!$this->_connection->prepare(...)){
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $this->_connection->errno, $this->_connection->error);
    die();
}
```

If you look at `$this->_connection->error`, you'll see the following error,

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

This issue has been documented in many forums, such as:

- From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html),

  *If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.*
- From this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614741/5517143),

  *You can't have two simultaneous queries because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default (for prepared statements;...*

### Solution:

Execute the commands in correct order, ([**See this example code**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples))

1. Open up the connection (Once: at the very beginning, not during the execution of every query)
2. Create a prepared statement
3. Bind parameters
4. Execute the query
5. Bind result variables
6. Fetch value into those bound variables
7. Close the statement object
8. Close the connection (Once: at the very end, not during the execution of every query)

(Follow steps 2 to 7 for executing all of your queries, though one or more steps might be optional based on of your query)

So the solution is, close the previous statement object before calling `->prepare()` again. Take this method call `$this->unsetPsSelectUsers();` out of the `setPsSelectUsers()` method and place it before the `if ($this->_psSelectUsers->fetch()){...}else{...}` block of `isPostingAllowed()` and `checkUserAuthentication()` methods. Furthermore, save the status of `$this->_psSelectUsers->fetch()` method call in a variable and use it in the subsequent `if` block. So your code should be like this:

```
public function isPostingAllowed() {
    $this->setPsSelectUsers($this->_connection->prepare("Select * from userpermissions where userpermissions.UserId = ? and userpermissions.PermissionId = 1"));
    if(!$this->_psSelectUsers){
        printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $this->_connection->errno, $this->_connection->error);
        die();
    }
    $this->_psSelectUsers->bind_param('i',$this->UserId);
    $this->_psSelectUsers->execute();
    $status = $this->_psSelectUsers->fetch();
    $this->unsetPsSelectUsers();
    if ($status){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private function setPsSelectUsers($stmt){
    $this->_psSelectUsers= $stmt;
}

private function unsetPsSelectUsers() { 
    if (isset($this->_psSelectUsers)) { 
        $this->_psSelectUsers->close(); 
        unset($this->_psSelectUsers);
    }
}

public function checkUserAuthentication() {
    $this->setPsSelectUsers($this->_connection->prepare("SELECT UserLogInName FROM Users WHERE UserLogInName=? AND UserPassword=?"));
    if(!$this->_psSelectUsers){
        printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $this->_connection->errno, $this->_connection->error);
        die();
    }
    $this->_psSelectUsers->bind_param('ss',$this->UserLogInName, $this->UserPassword);
    $this->_psSelectUsers->execute();
    $status = $this->_psSelectUsers->fetch();
    $this->unsetPsSelectUsers();
    if ($status){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Moreover, you don't have to use this `setPsSelectUsers()` method anymore, you can directly use the property `$_psSelectUsers` in your methods like this:

```
$this->_psSelectUsers = $this->_connection->prepare(...);
```

Comment: First Thank you for your great help :) , second the problem is solved, the sign up page is working good now so I considered this as accepted answer, although there is new bugs poped up  from no where :) and it seems to have infinite loop. I think I will test and rewrite many parts of the code. Anyway Thank You so much for your kind help :) :)

Comment: @ParcRoi You're welcome! ;-) Glad I could help. *Cheers!*