# why is an 'Commands out of sync' error while executing multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to truncate multiple tables and trying the following code to achieve that.

```
$tables = array("students","fees","test","jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec");
for($i=0;$i<15; $i++){
    $del_all = "TRUNCATE TABLE ".$tables[$i];
    $res = $conn->query($del_all); //line no. 221
    $res->store_result();
    $res->free_result();
    $res->close();
}
echo "<div class='w3-panel w3-green w3-display-container' style='width:40%;'>
                <span onclick='this.parentElement.style.display='none''
                class='w3-button w3-large w3-display-topright'>&times;</span>
                <p>Records Cleared!</p>
            </div>";
```

After executing, it is giving

> error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in
>   C:\wamp\www\classlearn\delete.php on line 221`.

I have applied `$res->store_result();`, `$res->free_result();` and `$res->close();` then, also, I am getting this error. What is the problem? 
My question is not a duplicate. I have implemented `store_result()` , `free_result()` and `close()` which the previous question asker didn't implemented.

Comment: It should be `$conn->close()` instead of `$res->close()` ..

Comment: I will try to do it in  single query:- https://3v4l.org/5LudU

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Just tried it, not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: @AlivetoDie this approach is also not working giving same error

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have implemented `store_result()` and `close()`. link you given has not added this in his/her code. My question is different from that.