# commands out of sync error though executing only one query

Tags: php

I am executing a single query, then also why there is error `'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in C:\wamp\www\classlearn\delete.php on line 65`. Such error may cause during simultaneous queries, which is not in my case. Here's my code:

```php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $rn = $_POST['del_rn'];
    $check = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM `students` WHERE rollno=?");
    $check->bind_param("s",$rn);
    $check->execute();
    $rows = $check->fetch();
    if($rows>0){
        $stmt_student = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `students` WHERE rollno=?"); //line 65
        $stmt_student->bind_param("i",$rn);

        if($stmt_student->execute()){ 
            echo "Record deleted successfully";
        } else{ 
            echo "Record not deleted";
        }
    } else{ 
        echo "Record does not exists";
    }
}
```

I have checked query is correct and also tried with direct `query` instead of `prepare` statement. But, the effect is same. What could be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: You try to run DELETE before SELECT is finished.

Comment: @Dharman my question is not duplicate. Your link redirects to a question where the asker has simultaneous queries in code. But, this is not in my case.

Comment: @Dharman so, what could be the solution? I want to achieve both things

Comment: Change fetch to `get_results()->fetchAll()` and see if it helps. You try to execute 2 queries at the same time. SELECT and DELETE.

Comment: @Dharman it worked by putting `$check->close()`