# "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" Error

Tags: php, sql

Getting this error "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Here is the code

```
$sql = file_get_contents("setup.sql");
    $sql = str_replace(["WEBSITE_URL", "LICENSE_KEY", "WEBSITE_TITLE"], [rtrim($website->website_url, "/"), $website->license, empty($website->w_title) ? "'Script By JUICYCODES.COM'" : "'" . $website->w_title . "'"], $sql);
    if ($db->multi_query($sql)) {
        do {
            $query = $db->use_result();
        } while (!$db->next_result());
    }
```

Can Anyone solve the issue?

Comment: There is already a question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)