# Mysqli with PHP: How to access stored results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a prepared and bound `SELECT` statement that, when executed, returns a single row:

```
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $id);
  $statement->execute();
```

But I need to free mysqli to do a different `SELECT`.

I understand that I need to use `$statement->store_result();`, but when I try to fetch the result, it simply returns *true*: `$result=$statement->fetch();`

I was originally using

```
$result = $statement->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

But I need to be able to do another `SELECT` query while I retain access to the original result row, and when I attempt to do so using `get_result()`, it throws an error: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

How do I formulate the code so that I can execute another query while at the same time access the data contained in the previous resultant row? How do I access the stored data?

I also tried to fetch the result and then store it in the internal buffer, but this produces the same error.

```
  $result=$statement->get_result();
  $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
  $statement->store_result();
```

This question was marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now), but I see no examples of how to use the `store_result()` method where I can actually access the resultant data from two different queries at the same time.

EDIT:

Code (trimmed for clarity)

```
function display_video($id,$order='ASC') {
  $mysqli = new mysqli(getenv('O_HOST'), getenv('O_USER'), getenv('O_PW'), getenv('O_DB'));
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      die("Cannot connect to DB: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

  $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `videos` WHERE `VidID` LIKE ? ORDER BY `Pub_date` $order";
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bind_param('s', $id);
  $statement->execute();
  $result=$statement->get_result();
  $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
  $statement->free_result();
  if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "<p>Video $id not found.</p>" . PHP_EOL;
    return false;
  }
//  <<<< Generate HTML >>>>
get_relations($row["VidID"],$row["lang"],$row['RelatedID'],$row['MediaID'],$mysqli,$related);
//  <<<< Generate more HTML using $related >>>>
  $mysqli->close();
}

function get_relations($id,$lang,$relID,$mID,$db,&$rel_list){
  do{
    $sql="SELECT `data` FROM `videos` WHERE `vidID` LIKE ?";
    $statement=$db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('i',$relID);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $statement->free_result();
//      <<<< Process data >>>>
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }while($relID!=$id);
  return true;
}
```

(The `` `data` `` field in the SQL is really a number of different fields.)

Notice the two lines that must be included to prevent the described error:

`$statement->free_result();`

Comment: What's the problem with `get_result`?

Comment: I edited the question to express it better. I just don't have a grasp of how to use the method to accomplish the intended purpose. In the meantime, I am trying ```$statement->free_result()```, which actually may be more useful for what I need.

Comment: Indeed, either ```$statement->close()``` or ```$statement->free_result()``` allow me to execute another ```SELECT``` query after copying the results to an array for processing, while ```$statement->store_result()``` produces the error as described. Unfortunately, the documentation led me down the latter rabbit hole and wasted a lot of time. And despite the many similar questions in this vein I've seen, I still have no idea how one is supposed to use that method, so the question is still open. Does it really even work?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? When you use `get_result` it will fetch all results and there will no longer be any pending results on the wire. If you use `store_result` it will also fetch all results. Closing the statement also fetches all results from the connection. It's all the same and neither one should prevent you from executing more queries. If you can clarify the problem in your question, it can get reopened.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you even want to use `store_result` or `close` in the first place. What possible use do you have for it? If you don't know what they do, don't use them. Just use `get_result`. But if you are seeing this error when using `get_result` then you must be doing something wrong way before that.

Comment: Also, a a word of advise. Don't use mysqli if you don't have to. If you are starting a new project you should always pick PDO. Mysqli is only for old projects because of how difficult it is to use correctly.

Comment: To give you some idea of what a proper mysqli prepared statement should look like take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php These pages show how to use it without using any `store_result` or `free_result` nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have used PDO before, but I am adapting an existing system that uses mysqli. I just want it to work, and using ```free_result``` or ```close``` are the only ways I've found that work. I retrieve one record, which has a field with the key to another record and so on in a short chain of a handful of linked records. But without closing the statement or freeing the results, it generates the mentioned error when I include the code for the next statement preparation.

Comment: Are you calling a stored procedure by any chance?

Comment: My procedure is as follows:
1. Connect, ```prepare```, ```bind_param```, ```execute```
2. ```get_result```, ```fetch_assoc```
3. <process data>
4. call a separate function that populates an array with the list of linked data as described above, passing the database variable.
From the second function: 
5. ```prepare```, ```bind_param```, ```execute```
6. ```get_result```, ```fetch_assoc```
7. <process>
8. Loop to Step 5 until end of chained records.

The above fails unless I add a step 
2b. ```free_result``` (or ```close```), and again as 6b.

Comment: For the code SHOWN here, NO error like this is possible. So either there is no question at all (just use get_result, REMOVE any store_result call and get rid of every close/free) or there is some code behind  <<<< Process data >>>> is causing this error.